# Solving $5^x - 2^x = 117$ using modular arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponential-diophantine-equations

I'm trying to solve $5^x - 2^x = 117$. The solution is very easy to find by inspection, however I'm having difficulty trying to find reasoning specifically using modular arithmetic where the solution pops up naturally (i.e. not having to guess).

My work so far has been:

$5^x - 2^x\,$ is strictly increasing and positive only for $x>0$ so the original equation must only have $1$ solution. Assuming there exists an integer solution, the following holds true:

$$\begin{align*}5^x-2^x &= 117\\5^x-125&=2^x-8\\125(5^{x-3}-1)&=8(2^{x-3}-1)\end{align*}$$

This tells us $2^{x-3}-1$ has to be a multiple of $125$, so $$2^{x-3}\equiv1\mod125$$Since $\text{ord}_{125}(2)=100$, $x-3 = 100k\,$ for some $k\in\Bbb N$. Similarly, $5^{x-3}-1$ has to be a multiple of $8$, and $\text{ord}_{8}(5)=2$, so $x-3 = 2m \,$ for some $m \in\Bbb N$. The first equation already encapsulates the second one so $x=100k+3$.

This is where I'm stuck. Any help towards reaching the $x=3$ solution using modular arithmetic would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Note that modular techniques are only available if $x$ is known to be a non-negative integer...was that given here?  If it was, then note that $x\equiv 3 \pmod {100}$ solves the problem since $103$ is already far too large.

Comment: @lulu I excluded negative numbers by the outlined reasoning, then I assumed it was an integer for the rest of it. Yes, $x=103$ is very large, but I am wondering what I would have done if the question was something like $5^x-2^x=48826077$. I wouldn't have been able to easily guess the solutions or exclude intervals for $x$. So I'm looking for an idea/method where you don't have to guess-and-check solutions.

Comment: There is no reason on earth to imagine that the answer is an integer, so these techniques are not generally applicable.  Numerical methods are faster anyway.  Modular techniques are good for proving that solutions to Diophantine problems over the integers do not exist...they aren't very good at finding solutions.

Comment: Thank you for that response, it's insightful.

Comment: @typo - concerning your comment on number $a=48826077$: it requires $5^x >a$ so $x \approx \lceil \log_5(a) \rceil=11$ so you try $5^{11} - a $ and see whether this is in the near of $2^{11}$. Well, this is not a search with a diophantine method - but suitable to get a cheap guess of value or interval... on the other hand, after you have found that $x=100k+3$ then you can simply note that $ (5/2)^{100k+3} -1 = 119 /2^{100k+3}$ cannot exist for $k \gt 0$, since the lhs is much larger than $1$ when $k>0$ and the rhs is much smaller than $1$ ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modular arithmetic cannot provide a bound to the solution, so you must develop one independently.

If $x$ is a positive integer, then $2^x\le(2/5)(5^x)$ and thus

$(3/5)(5^x)\le117.$

So $5^x\le195$, meaning a positive integer solution cannot be greater than $3$.

It is then sufficient to solve the equation only using $\bmod 5$. Thus we find

$0-2^x\equiv2$

$2^x\equiv3\equiv8$

whose only solution within the bound $x\le3$ is $x=3$.

Comment: Your $<$s should be $\le$s in case $x=1$, unless you manually exclude that first viz. $5^1-2^1=3\ne117$.

Comment: OK, modified it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is very clear. I understand all but one line: how did you get $(3/5)(5^x)\le117$? I'm getting $(7/5)(5^x)\le117$ which is a bit higher.

Edit: nevermind, found my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

we may also allow separate exponents for $2,5,$ Very similar to what you did, there is a certain amount of factoring to find useful primes, in this problem we need add   just $41$  to the list $2,5,41.$

To begin with $$ 5^u - 125 = 2^v -8$$
As you also used, make new exponents $x,y$ so that
$$  125 \left( 5^x -1  \right)  =  8 \left( 2^y - 1 \right)  $$
With the guess that we already know the largest possible $u,v:$   **ASSUME**   that both $x,y \geq 1 $ in the above.

To reduce the size of the numbers, we point out: as $2^y - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod 5,$  we know already that $4|x.$  Just a little more, from  $2^y - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod {25},$  we find that $20|x.$
This is enough to go on:  $$ 2^{20} - 1 |  2^y - 1 $$   and
$$   2^{20} - 1 =  3 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 11 \cdot 31 \cdot  41 . $$
Thus $41 |  2^y-1.$  This forces $41 |  5^x - 1 ,$   therefore $20 | x.$

We don't need that much. It is enough to use $4|x.$  Because
$$   5^4 - 1 =  2^4 \cdot 3 \cdot 13  $$ That is, $5^x-1$ is divisible by $16;$  we reach the needed **contradiction** from $$  16 | 8  \left( 2^y - 1 \right).  $$ It cannot be true unless $y=0.$

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to follow some of the reasoning. Can you explain how you got the conclusions $2\big|x$, $20\big|x$ and $2^{20} - 1 \big|  2^y - 1$ near the middle?